# Can anyone help me understand a part of the code in this Triangle Class?

Tags: python

New to coding and have a question. There is a part of this code that I don't understand and am wondering if anyone can clarify. The code works as it should but I do not understand this one piece. What is this part of the code doing?

```
filledTrue = (filled == 1)
```

I am guessing it is passing filledTrue to the Superclass if filled equals 1, but I have not seen code used like this yet so am not sure. Do the parentheses work like an If statement without the Else component?

Thanks so much!

Here is the full code:

```
class GeometricObject:
    def __init__(self, color =  "green" , filled = True):
        self.__color = color
        self.__filled = filled

    def getColor(self):
        return self.__color

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.__color = color

    def isFilled(self):
        return self.__filled

    def setFilled(self, filled):
        self.__filled = filled

    def __str__(self):
        return  "color: "  + self.__color + \
             " and filled: "  + str(self.__filled)


class Triangle(GeometricObject):
    def __init__(self, side1 = 1.0 , side2 = 1.0, side3 = 1.0):
        super().__init__()
        self.__side1 = side1
        self.__side2 = side2
        self.__side3 = side3

    def getSide1(self):
        return self.__side1

    def setSide1(self, side1):
        self.__side1 = side1

    def getSide2(self):
        return self.__side2

    def setSide2(self, side2):
        self.__side2 = side2

    def getSide3(self):
        return self.__side3

    def setSide3(self, side3):
        self.__side3 = side3

    def setArea(self):
        self.area = area

    def getArea(self):
        s = (self.__side1 + self.__side2 + self.__side3) / 2
        area = (s * (s - self.__side1) * (s - self.__side2) * (s - self.__side3)) ** 0.5
        return area

    def getPerimeter(self):
        perimeter = self.__side1 + self.__side2 + self.__side3
        return  perimeter

    def triangleString(self):
        return "Triangle: Side 1: " + self.__side1 + "Side 2: " + self.__side2 + "Side 3: " + self.__side3

def main():
    side1 = eval(input("Enter a number for side 1: "))
    side2 = eval(input("Enter a number for side 2: "))
    side3 = eval(input("Enter a number for side 3: "))
    color = input("Enter a color for the triangle: ")
    filled = eval(input("To fill the triangle, enter 1, otherwise enter 0: "))
    filledTrue = (filled == 1)
    #set the variables in the classes
    triangleSolution = Triangle(side1, side2, side3)  # this sets the triangle sides in Triangle Class
    triangleSolution.setColor(color)  # this sets the color in the superclass (through subclass)
    triangleSolution.setFilled(filledTrue) # this sets the fill
    #get the variables in the classes with printout
    print("The triangle’s area is: ", triangleSolution.getArea(), '\n',
          "The perimeter is: ", triangleSolution.getPerimeter(), '\n',
          "The color is: ", triangleSolution.getColor(), '\n',
          "The color is filled: ", triangleSolution.isFilled())

main()
```

Comment: Arrgghh... Don't use `eval(...)` :(

Comment: It's just a boolean result. `a == b` produces either `True` or `False`. Boolean values are just another type of object, just like `42` or `"Hello world!"`.

Comment: The parentheses *here* do not have any meaning, not to Python.

Comment: What do you mean don't use eval(...)? Is that bad practice?

Comment: This is not idiomatic Python code. It is using Java-escue getters and setters, and uses `__` double underscores where none are needed (indicating that the author perhaps has misunderstood *class private names* for *private attributes* as used in Java privacy model (Python has no such privacy model).

Comment: The use of `eval()` is entirely not needed, the code could simply omit that call and use `filled == '1'` instead. `eval()` opens the door to the end-user entering arbitrary Python expressions and hack the program. `eval()` should be a last resort, not an easy way out when you want to convert strings to specific Python types.

Comment: Thank you Martijn! I get it now. I am creating "True" or "False" with the boolean inside the parentheses and then passing the variable that represents that Boolean result to the Triangle Class. You are the best! I am new to this forum so if there is a way to give credit to someone giving a solution let me know. :)

Comment: Ok I think I understand why not to use eval() in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Variables assigned to a comparator `x == y` or others (greater than, less than, etc) will take a value of a boolean (`True` or `False`):

```
x = 1==1 # True
y = 'a'=='b' # False
z = 2 <= 5 # True
```

Comment: The attributes are ***not*** private, there is no `c.__y` attribute, and never will be as the attribute has been renamed automatically. So `c._myclass__y` is perfectly readable, but that these attributes are renamed does not make them inaccessible. Python has no privacy model, the feature is there to add another namespace level to attributes to help avoid clashes with subclasses using the same name.

Comment: Yes, in the case that someone wanted to make something as private as they could in Python, that would be the analogous method. I realize the limitations of the introspective nature of Python, just figured I'd include it

Comment: When you see such names in code that is **clearly not designed to be subclassed by third-party developers that do not need to care about reserved attribute names**, they have not understood what the feature is for and have misunderstood how Python works.

Comment: Yes, but by doing so you perpetuate a myth that you need to use this for attributes at all. They make code harder to debug and maintain. The whole code example is simply a bad example, probably written by someone taught how to write Java first.

Comment: I am reading the comments after the code was deleted from the solution that you all are referring to.  Can you help me understand the underscores in Python then? The book I am learning from uses them which is why I have them as I do in the code in the original question. Should there not be underscores?

Comment: @CorrieStewart Per Martijn Pieters comment on both my answer and your question, the underscores are there for class attributes that are not to be inherited to another class. If you are not using polymorphism, this isn't really a concern and you can build your code without the underscores with no consequence. Martijn Pieters can keep me honest on this one, as my understanding was a bit skewed prior